# Analysis Successful but Fails to Load

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Jenkins is doing my build, and I see the following in the Console for SonarQube:

> INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse
>   http://server:9000/dashboard/index/COMMON INFO: Note that you will be
>   able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the
>   submitted analysis report INFO: More about the report processing at
>   http://server:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVzTu41p8QwJREfJ0twh

Java 1.8.131
Windows Server 2012 R2
SonarQube Version 6.4 (build 25310)

When I go to SonarQube the analysis failed to load. Looking at the details I get this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.getArrayInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:334)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter.access$100(CollectionComponentParameter.java:49)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.CollectionComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(CollectionComponentParameter.java:139)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:141)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:283)
    at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerImpl.java:92)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.sonar.ce.taskprocessor.CeWorkerImpl.call(CeWorkerImpl.java:35)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class okhttp3.OkHttpClient
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:71)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:621)
    at org.picocontainer.containers.ImmutablePicoContainer.getComponent(ImmutablePicoContainer.java:40)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:718)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.OkHttpClientBuilder.systemDefaultSslSocketFactory(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:216)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.OkHttpClientBuilder.build(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:179)
    at org.sonar.server.util.OkHttpClientProvider.provide(OkHttpClientProvider.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$ExtendedDefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(ComponentContainer.java:69)
    ... 87 more
```

Any ideas on why the load is failing?

Comment: @slartidan - Question updated with version information.

Comment: have u been able to figure out what is wrong, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you start SonarQube server with openJDK, start SonarQube server  with oracle jdk.